# Access 2016: Display each group in it own page. How?

Tags: ms-access

I have made a database with contain report name **teacherInfo**. I would like to print each group in it own separate page so what is the current problem and how i can fix it ? Also i know that Report Header display only in the first page but can i display it on each separate page instead of using Report Header ?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90HFm0P2IoXOGFRVWdLekFwME0

Regards,

Comment: Your report appears to be VERY wide (like 15.5 inches). Make sure that the width of your report is no wider than the width of the paper you are using.  You should be able to move the elements in your report header into the page header (just close up the report header). They will then appear at the top of each page.

Comment: I change it to fit A4 size with 8.268 inches but still the result is same ?

Comment: Access seems to want the page width to be slightly less that 8 inches in order for it to fit on an A4 page in portrait mode. That may be to do with my Canon printer as much as anything. Try to make your report a bit narrower than 8 inches. Then try a print preview and see how it looks.

Comment: Thanks your right that happend with my printer canon too :)